# solution of the Diophantine equation of the form $(2^n)^x + p^y = z^2 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Can we find solutions of Diophantine equations of the form :

$$(2^n)^x + p^y = z^2 $$

where $k, x, y, z$ and $n$ are positive integers.

-Richard Simson

Comment: What  does p belong to?

Answer (score 3):

Some easily-spotted solutions:

1. $p = 0$, $nx$ is even, $z$ is a square root of $(2^{nx})$.
2. $x = y = 2$, $(2^{n},p,z)$ is a Pythagorean triple, e.g. $(4,3,5)$.
3. In 2., adding $k$ to $n$ and multiplying $p$ and $z$ by $2^{k}$ will produce a new solution for any positive integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution:

x = 1, p = 2, n even, y = n+3

Then, putting m = n/2:

$(2^n)^x + p^y = 2^n + 2^3.2^n = (1 + 2^3).2^n = 9.2^n = 9.4^m = (3.2^m)^2$

Comment: You have given good explanation.
can you generalize the method of solving the equation of the type $2^x$ + $19^y$ = $z^2$ has a solution (3, 0, 3). Also, $8^x$ + $19^y$ = $z^2$ has no solution. But, $8^x$ + $17^y$ = $z^2$ has a solution (2, 1, 9). I think these there are very close to each other in forms. But, finding solutions by generalizing is difficult. Can you clarify...plZ.

Comment: richard  I can't see a very close connection between what you are asking and my answer. You might like to post a new question.

Comment: @richard: Please do not use the answer box for anything but answering. You should probably register, and then edit the question to ask for further clarifications.